# Does Npgsql work fine with Aurora PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql, amazon-aurora

We would like to use AWS Aurora PostgreSQL with EF Core from our .NET5 application.
NET5 application to use AWS Aurora PostgreSQL with EF Core. I am considering using Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL as a database provider, but I am not sure if this will work with AWS Aurora PostgreSQL.
I've done a lot of research, but I can't find any good information about it, so if you know anything about it, please let me know.

Comment: It should work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.